# Change Spring findAll() return type

Tags: spring, interface, spring-data-jpa, overriding, spring-projections

I want to run Spring JPA's findAll() method but return all records but then without returning all the records. I want to return values from a Projection. Like

```
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Integer>{
    //How can I achieve this
    List<NamesOnly> findAll(); 
   //Which returns list of only student names;
}

public interface NamesOnly{
@Value("#{target.firstName+ ' ' + target.lastName}")
    String getFullName();
}
```

or Alternatively,

```
how to convert List<Student> given by default findAll() to List<NamesOnly>??
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to perform the change in another method, you can't change the repository return type which is defined by your: `extends CrudRepository<Student, Integer>`

Comment: No, I was taking of returning List<NamesOnly> from the default List<Student>  or if that's not possible how to convert List Class Types!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. Only create StudentDto one field : studentName and in StudentRepository do it :

```
  List<StudentDto> findAllStudent();
```

**StudentDTO.class**

```
public class StudentDTO {
       private String studentName //this is field you want return

     }
```

Or you can used anotation @JsonIgnore above field you don't want show when reponse look line :

```
  **Student.class**


  @JsonIgnore
  private String firstName //this is field you don't want spring reponse.
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, spring keep throwing exception saying "No property findAllOrder found for type Order!". Can someone elaborate ?